# Read a node with the foreign key of another node firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have a view to show "my created games" and at the moment I can only show the key of the item, but I want to access the node 'Games' with that key to get all its fields.

I know that de-normalizing and duplicating the fields that interest me in the node 'MisPartidasCreadas' -> idGame I can have the solution, but it seems very redundant to repeat so much information, as well as the maintenance that entails, not to mention if the base of data would require that information in more nodes or each node contains more than 50 fields (for exaggerating a bit).

I want to try to have the information unified in a single entity and not de-normalize.

Well, as the view of 'created games' returns all the matches in a firebase reference, because I go through that array and I make references to each starting node individually ... It does not work.

[image: JSON Database structure]

[image: MisPartidosCreadosPage]

And the provider Partidas.ts contains ...

[image: Partidas.ts]

I've also tried the 1:53 minute code of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA&index=6&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s and it does not work either, it always returns empty snap.val().

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?
Greetings.

Comment: You've posted your Database Structure and your Code as Pictures. Please replace that with text (JSON Database structure) as it makes it more searchable and easier for us to use it in our answers.

Comment: I already did it, thanks.